# Bootstrap Tags Input doesn't work with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I try to make a Project Manager. It can add more people to one project.
So, I use [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) and follow these [examples](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/): Typeahead, Object tags.

Instead of remote data, I have a json string storage in hidden input. So, I modify the example as:

```
  var users = new Bloodhound({
    initialize: false,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [{id:1,fullname:'aaa'},{id:2,fullname:'bbb'}],
    identify: function(obj) { return obj.id; }
  });
  var promise = users.initialize();
  promise.done(function(){
    var elt = $('#project_memebers');
    elt.tagsinput({
      itemValue: 'id',
      itemText: 'fullname',
      typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'fullname',
        valueKey: 'id',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
      }
    });
  })
  .fail(function() { console.log('Something goes wrong!')});
```

But nothing happens when I type "aaa"  or "bbb". No tag, no hint, no error output!

How can I make it does auto-complete and tag?

Comment: so sad! nobody knows these?

Answer (score 0):

datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('fullname'),

Comment: Could use editing to show some explanation of why it answers the question. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO, typically at least some explanation is desired.

Comment: @pabo74-- This sort of terse response is barely OK in a comment, but in an answer you should attempt to explain what is wrong with the OPs code and how you propose to fix it.

Comment: In order to display suggestion list, you must  provide a key that Bloodhound will get. So `Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text')` is wrong because there is no `text` property in your data object, and you have to replace it with your `fullname`. (if you replace it with `id` then Bloodhound will show you a list of `id` instead)